# The main difference between SharedFlow and StateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin

What are the differences between **SharedFlow** and **StateFlow**?

And how to use these in **MVI** architecture? is it better to use simple **Flow** or these as states and events?

Comment: read [this post](https://proandroiddev.com/mvi-architecture-with-kotlin-flows-and-channels-d36820b2028d)

Comment: StateFlow is a SharedFlow that keeps a history of one value that you can inspect directly without collecting.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So core developers decided to create whole new class that is only different from actual implementation with a single configuration? Does not make any sense.

Comment: @Farid I added an answer that I think should clarify what you're asking about. One other note. StateFlow is not a subclass of SharedFlow. It's a sub-interface. The two underlying class implementations are not in a parent-child relationship. The underlying logic required to make StateFlow work is different and allows it to perform better than it would if built out of the same class as SharedFlow.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Flow is cold!, means it emits data only when it is collected.
Also Flow cannot hold data, take it as a pipe in which water is flowing , data in flow only flows , not stored(no .value function).

Unlike Flow, StateFlow and SharedFlow are hot streams means they emit data even when there is no collector. Also if there are multiple collectors, a new Flow will be run for each collector, completely independent from each other.
SharedFlow and StateFlow are Flows that allow for sharing itself between multiple collectors, so that only one flow is effectively run for all of the simultaneous collectors. If you define a SharedFlow that accesses databases and it is collected by multiple collectors, the database access will only run once, and the resulting data will be shared to all collectors.

What are the differences between SharedFlow and StateFlow?

StateFlow

> > Stateflow takes an initial value through constructor and emits it immediately
> > when someone starts collecting.
> > Stateflow is almost identical to LiveData.
> > LiveData automatically unregisters the consumer when the view goes to the STOPPED
> > state. When collecting a StateFlow this is not handled automatically , you can
> > use repeatOnLifeCyCle scope if you want to unregister the consumer on STOPPED
> > state.
> > If you want current state use stateflow(.value).

SharedFlow

> > StateFlow only emits last known value , whereas SharedFlow can configure how many
> > previous values to be emitted.
> > If you want emitting and collecting repeated values , use sharedflow.

**Summary**

In summary, use StateFlow when you need to manage and share a single state with multiple collectors. Instead, use SharedFlow when you need to share a stream of events among collectors without holding any state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your "difference" section is just citing to the document without saying anything about real difference. If differences between them can be configured so that one can act like the other, why they created 2 different classes of the same implementation which are only different with few configurations? There must be implementation difference which you omitted and answered for the sake of answer.

Answer (score 17):

StateFlow is a subtype of SharedFlow that has more restricted configuration options (making it simpler to set up and better performing), but it has the addition of a `value` property.

StateFlow's `value` property represents its current value and can be checked from anywhere, including outside of a coroutine. In a MutableStateFlow, you can also emit values from the flow by setting this `value` property, even from outside any coroutine. MutableSharedFlow has a `tryEmit()` function that can be used from outside coroutines, but its success when called depends on current state and buffer configuration. On the other hand, setting `MutableStateFlow.value` *always* succeeds.

The existence of this concept of a *single current value* means some of the configurable features of a SharedFlow are not available, because they would break the concept. Here are some of the restrictions:

1. The `replay` has to be 1, because there is only 1 current value.
2. There cannot be any buffer aside from the 1 current value, because there is only 1 value. The one current value cannot be dropped, but old values are always dropped and never seen by a collector if it takes a while to collect the previous value.
3. It only determines the current value to be changed if you change it to a functionally inequivalent value. This is like enforcing the `distinctUntilChanged()` operator on a base SharedFlow.
4. A StateFlow **must** have an initial value, because it always has a current value. Base SharedFlow doesn't need an initial value.

Hot flows like SharedFlow and StateFlow are useful if your flow logic must monitor something or do IO, and you want to avoid repeating that time-consuming work when there are multiple possible collectors. On Android, it can be used to preserve the flow during a screen rotation, during which collectors might be destroyed and new collectors created to collect the same flow.

Answer (score 11):

The main difference between a SharedFlow and a StateFlow is that a StateFlow takes a default value through the constructor and emits it immediately when someone starts collecting, while a SharedFlow takes no value and emits nothing by default.