# Migrate to ObserveAsState in Jetpack Compose - null

Tags: state, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, nullable, android-viewmodel

I am a beginner trying to learn Kotlin by changing an old tutorial to Compose.

I have a ViewModel with

```
private val _registerStatus = MutableLiveData<Resource<String>>()
    val registerStatus: LiveData<Resource<String>> = _registerStatus

    fun register(email: String, password: String, repeatedPassword: String) {
        _registerStatus.postValue(Resource.loading(null))
        if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || repeatedPassword.isEmpty()) {
            _registerStatus.postValue(Resource.error("Please fill out all the fields", null))
            return
        }
        if(password != repeatedPassword) {
            _registerStatus.postValue(Resource.error("The passwords do not match", null))
            return
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = repository.register(email, password)
            _registerStatus.postValue(result)
        }
    }
```

and Fragment with:

```
 viewModel.registerStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
        result?.let {
            when(result.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    registerProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    showSnackbar(result.data ?: "Successfully registered an account")
                }
                Status.ERROR -> {
                    registerProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    showSnackbar(result.message ?: "An unknown error occurred")
                }
                Status.LOADING -> {
                    registerProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

How could I adapt this code to use Jetpack Compose?

I understand I need to use "ObserveAsState" in a Composable :

```
registerViewModel.registerStatus.observeAsState()
```

Truth is, I think I don't really understand the nullable issue, or what val result is doing, or what result ->  result?.let is doing, except being some way to pass a non-null value in? If removed, I must make registerStatus.status non-null or safe. So I can do the below:

```
@Composable
fun subscribeToObservers() {
  val registerStatus by registerViewModel.registerStatus.observeAsState()
when(registerStatus!!.status){
            Status.SUCCESS -> {

            }
            Status.ERROR -> {

            }
            Status.LOADING -> {

            }
         }
    }
```

, or do I need to get the "result" value over?

Anything to help me toward understanding the issues better would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using `!!` as that means you know that that variable is **never** null. Your application is going to crash if the variable is ever null when going through this piece of code.

I want also to note that logically, you might not be able to find a scenario in which your variable is going to be null so you might get tempted to use `!!` but it is better to avoid it just in case.

Using `nullableVariable?.let { -> nonNullVariable }` is much safer as it only runs if the variable is not null. Unlike `!!`, it won't cause a crash if the variable is null.

I would write the code like this:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun subscribeToObservers() {
        val registerStatus by registerViewModel.registerStatus.observeAsState()
        registerStatus?.let { nonNullRegisterStatus ->
            when(nonNullRegisterStatus) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {}
                Status.ERROR -> {}
                Status.LOADING -> {}
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can approach this:

### Compose style

##### ViewModel

```
private val _registerStatus : MutableState<Resource<String>> = mutableStateOf(Resource.init(null))
val registerStatus: State<Resource<String>> = _registerStatus

fun register(email: String, password: String, repeatedPassword: String) {
    _registerStatus.value = Resource.loading(null)
    if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || repeatedPassword.isEmpty()) {
        _registerStatus.value = Resource.error("Please fill out all the fields", null)
        return
    }
    if(password != repeatedPassword) {
        _registerStatus.value = Resource.error("The passwords do not match", null)
        return
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = repository.register(email, password)
        _registerStatus.value = result
    }
}
```

##### Composable

```
@Composable
fun subscribeToObservers() {
    val registerStatus by viewModel.registerStatus
    when(registerStatus.status){
        Status.INIT -> {}
        Status.SUCCESS -> {}
        Status.ERROR -> {}
        Status.LOADING -> {}
    }
}
```

You can make `_registerStatus` not null in this way or if you initialize it as `private val _registerStatus : MutableState<Resource<String>?> = mutableStateOf(null)` handle null like:

```
@Composable
fun subscribeToObservers() {
    val registerStatus by viewModel.registerStatus
    when(registerStatus.status){
        Status.INIT -> {}
        Status.SUCCESS -> {}
        Status.ERROR -> {}
        Status.LOADING -> {}
        null -> {}
    }
}
```

### Kotlin style

##### ViewModel

```
private val _registerStatus : MutableStateFlow<Resource<String>> = mutableStateOf(Resource.init(null))
val registerStatus: StateFlow<Resource<String>> = _registerStatus

fun register(email: String, password: String, repeatedPassword: String) {
    _registerStatus.tryEmit(Resource.loading(null))
    if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || repeatedPassword.isEmpty()) {
    _registerStatus.tryEmit(Resource.error("Please fill out all the fields", null))
        return
    }
    if(password != repeatedPassword) {
        _registerStatus.tryEmit(Resource.error("The passwords do not match", null))
        return
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = repository.register(email, password)
        _registerStatus.tryEmit(result)
    }
}
```

##### Composable

```
@Composable
fun subscribeToObservers() {
    val registerStatus by viewModel.registerStatus.collectAsState()
    when(registerStatus.status){
        Status.INIT -> {}
        Status.SUCCESS -> {}
        Status.ERROR -> {}
        Status.LOADING -> {}
        null -> {}
    }
}
```

MutableStateFlow are thread safe and kotlin's solution to xJava `This method is thread-safe and can be safely invoked from concurrent coroutines without external synchronization.`
Kotlin provides one more type of flow called `SharedFlow` and it's upon your use case to use `SharedFlow` or `StateFlow`.
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow
[The main difference between SharedFlow and StateFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162586/the-main-difference-between-sharedflow-and-stateflow)